# Android UI navigation within Activity Advice and best practice

Tags: android, android-fragments, view

I'am stuck! 
I am developing my first Android App, so I am considered as a beginner. I have some programming background, so I managed to solve the first problems myself. But now I am at a point where I don't know how to solve several problems. So please share your eternal wisdom with me.

I am developing a game. I want the menu to be in a virtual phone. The picture below describes best what I want to achieve. Don't be confused by the words, I am from Germany.
Einstellungen = preferences ...

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3565/2xwgz3al_png.htm

When I am pressing the menu-button a fragment gets called. At the moment the layout of the fragment contains relative layout with android : background set to that entire image. What I want to achieve is that the phoneframe stays all the time, only the view (RED) will change. With up and down buttons I want to be able to move the chooser (BLUE) to the different menuitems. If I press OK (YELLOW) the selected item is called an e new view slides from the right side in the RED area. Hope that's clear.

So my questions are:

1. How do I get the RED area to that phoneframe? Maybe a LinearLayout with fixed Width and Height? But i cant image that as a good solution.
2. How do I animate the chooser (Blue) to the different menupoints by clicking up and down?
3. How would you perform the switch between the views inside of the phone Frame.
4. I want to perform all of that in that only fragment. Or is there a better solution?
5. I do not need the code for that all, only a push, a start or ideas so I can start googleing in the right directions.

Big Text an many questions, I hope you can take a little time for me, THANKS for answers.

Greetings from Germany (sorry if my English is not perfect)!

Comment: this sounds like at least 3 separate questions

Comment: This is a litte heavy I know:(  But all of it belongs together i guess. And I dont need solutions, i only want to pointed in the right direction. So if anyone only like to answer one point of my questions, its already helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you are asking a lot of question at once so it's difficult for me to give a clear answer. I am just going to explain to you how I would build a screen like that:

**1) The Layout:**

You Layout can simply be built with a RelativeLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flFragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="128dp" 
            android:background="#ff0000"/>


    <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDown"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:text="@string/fragment_main_button_down_text"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnUp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@id/btnDown"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/fragment_main_button_up_text"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnClose"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/btnDown"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="@string/fragment_main_button_close_text"/>

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnOk"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnDown"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="@string/fragment_main_button_ok_text"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So the layout is not that complicated, I set the background color of the FrameLayout to white so you can see were the fragment will be placed. Here is the Result:

[image]

This layout contains the buttons ok, close, up and down and of course a FrameLayout where our fragment is going to go. The layout in this example is by far not optimal, the problem is the positioning of the FrameLayout. It is as big as the screen with a fixed margin on all sides, so on different phones with different aspect ratios the FrameLayout is also going to have a different aspect ratio.

**2) The FragmentTransaction**

Now comes the interesting part, we are going to put our fragment into the FrameLayout container. But first, since we want the fragment to slide in from the right we have to write an ObjectAnimator like this:

```
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
                android:propertyName="xFraction"
                android:valueType="floatType"
                android:valueFrom="1.0"
                android:valueTo="0.0"
                android:duration="750" />
```

This describes a translation animation from right to left, if you want more information on that feel free to ask.

Now with that animation we have everything we need, now whenever you want to change the Fragment inside the phone you just have to perform a `FragmentTransaction` like this:

```
// We get our FragmentManager and begin our transaction
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

// Here we set our animations, to make the effect nicer I added a fade out animation for the old fragment
// The fade out animation is already built into Android
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.slide_in_right, android.R.animator.fade_out);

// We specify were we want the Fragment to go and pass along our new fragment instance.
// Calls to replace(), add(), remove()... always have to take place AFTER setCustomAnimations()
// Otherwise the animations are not applied to the fragments
transaction.replace(R.id.flFragmentContainer, fragment);

// With commit() the transaction is actually executed. You can replace multiple fragments in a single transaction
transaction.commit();
```

And here is the result, in my example app the FragmentTransaction is executed every time I press OK:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot. So you are saying that the fragment is only the phonescreen, right?  I didnt thought of that. 
In Germany it is 00:13, so i will try that after work and post wether it will work or not. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes the fragment would only be the phone's screen, glad I could help!

Comment: Please don't forget to upvote and accept my answer if I could help you :)

Comment: it seems that i can only upvote with more than 15 reputations, sorry.
I will try now to implement your approach, one quick question do i have left ^^ 

Thats all happening on a SurfaceView. I need something that is holding the phoneframe-layout in which i later intigrate the fragment. Is it possible to open a new acitvity with that layout, but the prevouse activity is still in sight? Like my picture shows?

Or do I add programmaticly a viewlayout to my surfaceview when I open the menu, and delete it after closing?